# Bijection between Binary Quadratic Forms and narrow Class group of Quadratic Number Fields over a non-$\mathbb Q$ base.

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, quadratic-forms, class-field-theory

It is well known that there is a bijection between $GL_2(\mathbb Z)$-equivalence classes of binary quadratic forms with $\mathbb Z$ coefficients of a fixed discriminant $D$, and the narrow class group of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{D})$.

Suppose $K$ is a number field, does there exist a similar correspondence between $GL_2(\mathcal O_K)$-equivalence classes of quadratic forms with $\mathcal O_K$ coefficients of some discriminant $D$, and the class group of the quadratic extension of $K$ with the same relative discriminant?

I suspect this may not be true in general, since relative discriminants would be an ideal and not an element of $\mathcal O_K$ in general so the correspondence would be a bit murky. But perhaps if extra conditions were imposed on $K$, e.g. $K$ has a trivial class group so $\mathcal O_K$ is a PID, then a similar correspondence might exist?

Comment: Is your first sentence true for all integers $D$, or only $D<0$? I think when $D>0$, the bijection is actually between the form class group and the *narrow* ideal class group of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})$.

Comment: In any case, [this MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/52815) and M. M. Wood's paper mentioned therein (https://arxiv.org/abs/1007.5508) may be helpful.

Comment: You are correct, I meant the narrow ideal class group and have edited my post. Sorry about that.
Thanks for the links provided, I will take a look.